# Download database in gzip

Tags: mysql, back-up, export, zip

With using the CraftCMS builtin database export feature, is it possible to specify the export config to have the file in `.gzip` instead of just `.zip`? If, yes, then how can I do it?

[image: backup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, the [UtilitiesController](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/controllers/UtilitiesController.php#L333) is hard-coded to use `.zip`:

```php
        $zip = new ZipArchive();

        if ($zip->open($zipPath, ZipArchive::CREATE) !== true) {
            throw new Exception('Cannot create zip at ' . $zipPath);
        }

        $filename = pathinfo($backupPath, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
        $zip->addFile($backupPath, $filename);
        $zip->close();

        return Craft::$app->getResponse()->sendFile($zipPath, null, [
            'mimeType' => 'application/zip',
        ]);
```

Comment: Thanks for a prompt answer! I am using Sequel Pro for the local development and it does not allow the import of `zip` files but works fine with `gzip`. I assume it is a common practice to import gzipped databases. Is there a way to import zipped databases?

Comment: @alljamin: Just unzip the file before loading into Sequel Pro. Unlike PHP-based web tools eg phpmyadmin, larger file sizes won't choke on import if that's what you're worried about.

Comment: @RitterKnight my concern with `zip` format is an inconvenience of having to unzip in order to import, wherewith `gzip` I can import without unzipping.

Comment: You should file a [feature request](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues) for gzip.